# Configuração pointcut AOP Spring

Tags: java, spring, orientação-a-aspectos

Tenho a configuração abaixo de pointcut no Spring 3

```xml
 <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="baseDaoPointcut"      expression="execution(* br.com.infraestrutura.domain.BaseDao+.*(..))" />
        <aop:pointcut id="baseBusinessPointcut" expression="execution(* br.com.infraestrutura.domain.BaseBusiness+.*(..))" />
       .....
```

Gostaria que esses dois pointcut fossem ignorada quando eu anotasse uma classe com uma determinada annotation, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
@NoTransactional
public interface VendaMercadoriaBusiness extends VendaMercadoriaBaseBusiness{}
```

ou

```
public interface VendaMercadoriaBusiness extends VendaMercadoriaBaseBusiness{
    @NoTransactional
    public void notificar();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De uma olhada nos designadores (PCDs) `@target`, `@within` e `@annotation` na [documentação do Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts). Veja que expressões de pointcut podem ser [combinadas](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-combining) com `&&`, `||` e `!` para formar regras como:

```
execution(* meuPacote.MinhaClasse+.*(..)) && !@annotation(meuPacote.NoTransactional)
execution(* meuPacote.MinhaClasse+.*(..)) && !@within(meuPacote.NoTransactional)
```

Como as expressões rapidamente se tornam complexas, vale a pena combinar regras nomeadas:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* br.com.infraestrutura.domain.BaseBusiness+.*(..)")
public void anyMethodInBaseBusinessOrSubtypes() {}

@Pointcut("@annotation(meuPacote.NoTransactional)")
public void nonTransactionalMethod() {}

@Pointcut("@within(meuPacote.NoTransactional)")
public void nonTransactionalClass() {}

@Pointcut("anyMethodInBaseBusinessOrSubtypes() && !nonTransactionalClass() && !nonTransactionalMethod()")
public void trasactionalBusinessMethod() {}
```

Infelizmente [não é possível combinar pointcuts nomeados com XML](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-or-xml), um dos bons motivos para migrar para anotações.
Outro detalhe a ser pensado é se você realmente quer ter uma anotação para métodos e tipos *não* transacionais (`@NoTransactional`). Para mim faria muito mais sentido demarcar métodos e tipos transacionais.

---

Alguns exemplos relacionados:

1. [SOen: @AspectJ pointcut for all methods of a class with specific annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10592877/664577)
2. [SOen: Pointcut for annotated methods or methods in annotated classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36193862/664577)
3. [SOen: Spring AOP pointcut expression to exclude annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37194564/664577)

Comment: Estou tentando essa solução pelo fato de o sistema ter uma arquitetura antiga onde define que todas as classes que implementam BaseDao ou BaseBusiness são transacionais, porem andam surgindo algumas exceções onde eu anotaria a classe como NoTransactional é os métodos transacionais com Transactional.

Answer (score 1):

Com base na resposta do Anthony Accioly cheguei a uma solução.

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NoTransactional {

}
```

Classe de declaração dos pointcuts:

```
@Aspect
public class AspectTransactionConfig {


    @Pointcut("execution(* br.com.infraestrutura.domain.BaseBusiness+.*(..))")
    public void baseBusinessPointcut() {}

    @Pointcut("@annotation(br.com.webfarma.sis.application.NoTransactional)")
    public void nonTransactionalMethod() {}

    @Pointcut("@within(br.com.webfarma.sis.application.NoTransactional)")
    public void nonTransactionalClass() {}

    @Pointcut("execution(* br.com.infraestrutura.domain.BaseDao+.*(..))")
    public void baseDaoPointcut() {}

    @Pointcut("baseBusinessPointcut() && !(nonTransactionalMethod() || nonTransactionalClass())")
    public void trasactionalBaseBusinessMethod() {}
}
```

XML de configuraçao:

```
  <aop:config>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="permissaoMetodoAdvice"      pointcut="br.com.webfarma.sis.application.AspectTransactionConfig.baseDaoPointcut()"                order="1" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="notificacaoEntidadeAdvice"  pointcut="br.com.webfarma.sis.application.AspectTransactionConfig.baseDaoPointcut()"                order="2" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="transactionDaoAdvice"       pointcut="br.com.webfarma.sis.application.AspectTransactionConfig.baseDaoPointcut()"      order="3" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="queryFilterManagerAdvice"   pointcut="br.com.webfarma.sis.application.AspectTransactionConfig.baseDaoPointcut()"                order="4" />

        <aop:advisor advice-ref="permissaoMetodoAdvice"      pointcut="br.com.webfarma.sis.application.AspectTransactionConfig.baseBusinessPointcut()"           order="1" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="transactionBusinessAdvice"  pointcut="br.com.webfarma.sis.application.AspectTransactionConfig.trasactionalBaseBusinessMethod()" order="2" />
    </aop:config>
```